# Calculating an average of averages in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to do something very simple but I'm obviously missing a trick! I want to get an average of average values but I want to include the weighting of the original average calculation. I'll use a stripped back version of what I'm attempting to do.

So let's say I have the following table

```
Product     date        RunInterval    AvgDuration_secs   Executions
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   A        29/12/19            1               1           100
   A        29/12/19            2               2            10
```

What I want to find out is what the average duration was for Product A on 29/12. All the things I've tried so far are giving me an average of 1.5 secs ie it's adding together the duration of 1 & 2 secs (3) and dividing by number of rows (2) to give 1.5. What I want to get to is to have the average but taking into account how often it runs so (100*1) + (10*2) / 110 = 1.09 secs. I've tried various attempts with GROUP BY statements and CURSORS but not getting there.

I'm evidently tackling it the wrong way! Any help welcome :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select product, date,
  round(1.0 * sum([Executions] * [AvgDuration_secs]) / sum([Executions]), 2) result
from tablename
group by product, date
```

I'm not sure if you want `RunInterval` or `AvgDuration_secs` in the 1st sum.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a5ee5fa5d9b120ba1376a9c07eab7bcd).
Results:

```
> product | date      | result        
> :------ | :---------| :-----
> A       | 29/12/2019| 1.09
```

Comment: It would make more sense to use `AvgDuration_secs` in the calculation.

Comment: Sure, but since the values are equal in the sample data it's up to the OP toclarify.

Comment: Maybe from this: *I want to get an average of average values* I guess it's `AvgDuration_secs`

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt reply. Yes that's now reporting exactly the way I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you got those results from a query or view that select from some table, then grouped by Product & date & RunInterval.

Then you could simply run a query that on that table that
groups only by the Product & date.

**An example:**

> ```
> --
> -- Sample data
> --
> CREATE TABLE sometable
> (
>   Product varchar(30), 
>   ExecutionDatetime datetime, 
>   RunInterval int
> );
>
> WITH RCTE_NUMS AS
> (
>    SELECT 1 AS n
>
>    UNION ALL
>    SELECT n+1
>    FROM RCTE_NUMS
>    WHERE n < 110
> )
> INSERT INTO sometable
> (Product, ExecutionDatetime, RunInterval) 
> SELECT 
> 'A' p, 
> DATEADD(minute,n*12,'2019-12-29 01:00:00') dt, 
> IIF(n<=100,1,2) ri
> FROM RCTE_NUMS
> OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000);
> ```
>
> ```
> 110 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select 
> Product, 
> cast(ExecutionDatetime as date) as [Date],
> AVG(1.0*RunInterval) AS AvgDuration_secs,
> COUNT(*) AS Executions
> from sometable t
> group by 
> Product, 
> cast(ExecutionDatetime as date)
> ORDER BY Product, [Date]
> ```
>
> ```
> Product | Date                | AvgDuration_secs | Executions
> :------ | :------------------ | :--------------- | ---------:
> A       | 29/12/2019 00:00:00 | 1.090909         |        110
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=4291db5f24ffc42c40f24db87c0d48ad)*

Comment: I didn't have the original durations anywhere as individual entries just the average durations per run interval. The solution forpas posted  managed to get the result i was after. Thanks for taking the time out to respond.

Comment: @flakey321 Yeah, I figured it was a situation like that.  Oh well, my point is still valid for when one has the original data.  Then one could even use things like [ROLLUP](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-rollup/)